# Season's Greetings usage

Tags: word-usage, christmas

Season's Greetings:

> - exclamation, noun [plural] UK    US
> - something written on a Christmas card as a way of expressing a Christmas greeting. (dictionary.cambridge.org)
> - A non-religious greeting uttered by well-wishers near the winter/solstice holiday period. (www.wiktionary.org)
> - Used as an expression of goodwill at Christmas or the New Year. (ODO)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Season%27s%20greetings&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CSeason%20%27s%20greetings%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bseason%20%27s%20greetings%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeason%20%27s%20Greetings%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSeason%20%27s%20greetings%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSEASON%20%27S%20GREETINGS%3B%2Cc0) Season's Greetings.

Is there a reason why this expression is used only to refer to the Christmas period and not to Easter or other holidays periods?

Related: [Is there a season's greeting for Halloween?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/is-there-a-seasons-greeting-for-halloween)

Comment: What point do you want to  make with the Ngram? That season's greetings were more common in the fifties? Illustrate when the usage begin? It might be better if you state this yourself rather than let users guess.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I added Ngram just as a piece of additional information. Though the expression is very common and natural for native speakers, it doesn't sound as such to non-natives who would tend to ask: what 'season' to the greetings refer to? Why is it used without referring to Christmas and the New Year? And why is it not used for other holidays periods?. My intent was to look for an answer about its origin and usage that might help in that respect!! Btw Happy New Year :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression **Christmas season** pretty much covers all the Christian festivities related to the birth of Christ. But there is another festivity which uses the term *season* and that is the **season of Lent**.

[image]

In fact if we look back to the 18th century, we can see that the phrase *season of Lent* (blue) was more in use than its winter counterpart. Lent was an essential and solemn period in the Christian calendar, the forty days of "fasting" preceded the most holy of feasts, Easter Sunday. It was a significant period that stretched across two months: March and April.

[image]

For many Roman Catholics the Christmas season begins on 8th December with the [feast of the immaculate conception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Immaculate_Conception) but traditionally it begins on the fourth Sunday before Christmas  and lasts until Epiphany, January 6th. Coincidentally this period covers more or less forty days.

From *Christmas season* to *Season's greetings*, written with or without the initial capital letter, the catchphrase appeared on Christmas cards and letters (snail mail) addressed  to friends and families. The phrase *seems* to have appeared in print from the [1860s onwards](https://www.google.it/search?q=seasons%20greetings&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1860%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1870&tbm=bks)

1861

> We offer our readers, far and near, the season's greetings — of a Christmas gone and the New Year dawning.

However a poem dated **1836** but printed in Amsterdam, New York in 1865, shows the phrase existed in the early 19th century and was not confined to Victorian England.

*Recreations of Leisure Hours: [A Collection of Poems](https://books.google.it/books?id=4dACAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22season%27s%20greetings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZA-lVJ7rOobfasfegkA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAThk#v=onepage&q=%22season's%20greetings%22&f=false)* by Xenophon Haywood

> The year in prospect, twelve short months ago,
>   How soon its days are numbered! We exchanged
>   The season's greetings, and with feelings kind
>   Expressed our mutual wishes that its scenes
>   Might all be bright and joyous.  Welcome wish,
>   And willingly believed; for hope has power
>   To turn the mind from dissapointments [sic] past,
>   Directing it to future joys, all bright,
>   And easy of attainment.   ...

Answer (score 5):

Because Christmas cards were the most commonly sent type of greeting card for which the phrase made sense ("compliments of the season" is a very poor choice of words if you wish to win your valentine's heart).

They are also the only sort of card that really covers a holiday season, as even a Victorian person in the UK who was assuming they would be addressing someone celebrating the predominant holidays of that culture would be extending their well-wishing to cover New Year's/Hogmanay as well as the Christmas period it lies in the middle of.

While the greeting arose during that period, it has a further advantage in covering other holidays that are celebrated at the same period, making it a relatively popular choice among those who give those holidays more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Hanukkah, Kwanzaa, Christmas, Festivus, New Years, Winter Solstice, Boxing Day, Advent, etc. all within a month and generic blessings to cover all aspects of the winter "season" seems appropriate whereas other holiday periods are generally punctuated by a single significant holiday event.  Easter might be one where an overlap with Passover might be significant, but these would not be as much of a greeting to someone outside one's faith that would necessarily need to be generically covered by seasonal greetings.

All this may eventually change, of course, over time, but a whole month (plus, if one includes Thanksgiving) of festivities versus generally a single day holiday seems to be more appropriately applied as a season.