# Why is it “Merry” Christmas, but “Happy” New Year?

Tags: etymology, christmas

*Happy* Christmas just sounds wrong to my American ear. (I do get that it is customary in England.)  *Merry* New Year, equally so.  Of the two, Christmas is the younger holiday and yet its greeting seems to be the more archaic.

So, my question is this: how did these greeting wishes get stuck with these holidays, and not the reverse?

Comment: They're perfectly comfortable with _Happy Christmas_ in the UK...

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/getting-into-the-spirit/) from our very own [Marthaª](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/1547/martha). There might be some interesting titbits in there for you

Comment: Related: [Determining which good sentiment to wish at each holiday](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44588/determining-which-good-sentiment-to-wish-at-each-holiday)

Comment: Mary is mother of Jesus.. and we celebrate his birthday as Christmas.. it might be said Mary Christmas olden days..

Comment: @balanv, that is incorrect. The etymology of *Merry* isn't related to the name *Mary* at all. One of English's strengths over many other European languages is that we carefully preserve the etymology and ethnic origins of a word in its spelling. Of course, that does make our spelling ridiculously complex. In any event, *merry* comes from the Old English *myrige* meaning "pleasing" or "agreeable". *Mary* is an Anglicization of a Latin word from a Greek word from the Hebrew word name *MRYM* that is related to a word for "rebellion".

Comment: Many of my relatives say "Happy Christmas", but it sounds wrong to my ear too.

Comment: @Affable Geek: Will the OP pl see the answers and comments.

Comment: I wonder whether North American *Merry Christmas* or British *Happy Christmas* is the older of the uses, and if so, just when the shift from the older to the newer version happened, and why.

Comment: ["When did we start saying 'Merry Christmas'?" answered](http://askville.amazon.com/start-Merry-Christmas-Happy-Clement-Moore-poem/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=428207)

Comment: British people don't generally use happy christmas instead of merry, @blazemonger 's link that says that is quite simply wrong. The queen says happy in her speech because she personally doesn't like the word merry. But you can't get more British than Charles Dickens who referred to our use of merry in the christmas carol in 1840 something.

Comment: Another example, the song "We Wish You a Merry Christmas" written in England before 1935

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the definitions of *merry* and *happy*, I would suggest that *merry* implies more short-term jollity, and *happy* more long-term contentment. That would square well with the *Merry Christmas* and *Happy New Year* usage.

The definitions of *merry* I found [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/merry) and [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/merry), and for *happy* [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/happy) and [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/happy).

It might also be worth noting that *merry* is used in phrases like *[play merry hell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/merry+hell)*, *[play Merry Andrew](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merry-andrew)* and the alternative meaning of *[merry (meaning 4)](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/merry)* meaning somewhat inebriated, which are all short-term (one hopes) states of affairs.

Comment: Many people probably eat more at Christmas and drink more on New Year's Eve

Comment: "Happy New Year"  though is not a wish for an enjoyable New Year's Eve, when this drinking takes place. It is a wish for a happy year to come.

Comment: Then why is it Happy Halloween? :/

Comment: @AbhinavPandey: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/is-there-a-seasons-greeting-for-halloween

Answer (score 9):

> [mer·ri·ment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merriment)
>   a state of enjoyable exuberance; playful fun
>   noun /ˈmerēmənt/  
>   Gaiety and fun
>   - her eyes sparkled with merriment

> [Happiness](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=happiness&use1913=on)
>   Hap"pi*ness, n. [From Happy.]
>   1. Good luck; good fortune; prosperity.
>   - *All happiness bechance to thee in Milan!* Shak.

*Merriment* is having some good fun, while *happiness* is a much broader term, relating to overall well-being with all necessities of life, and so on.

Christmas is a time of celebration and therefore a 'Merry Christmas' would be appropriate. A new year, as in 'Happy New Year', on other hand, extends over a whole year (and further on) and as such the sense of good luck, good fortune and prosperity provided by *Happy* would be appropriate.

Comment: You seem to have said exactly what I intended to write as an answer here. :)

Comment: @ikartik90: *We* wrote the answer, then! :) MerryXMas!

Comment: Merry Christmas. :)

Answer (score 1):

Historically, Christmas time meant mischief and drinking.

> But without the business of gift-giving that sprang up in the 19th
> century, Christmas might still be what it once was for many people: a
> riotous bacchanalia in which drunken gangs brawled in the streets and
> bashed their way into houses demanding money and alcohol.

(From "The Capitalists Who Saved Christmas" by Jason Zweig, WSJ, December 26, 2020, page B4.)

> In the 16th through the early 19th centuries, according to the Oxford
> English Dictionary, “merry” was a synonym for “drunk.” That
> connotation still lingered when, in Charles Dickens’s “A Christmas
> Carol” (1843), two men “wished each other Merry Christmas in their can
> of grog.”

(op. cit.)

So at least in the 16th c., people were getting merry (= drunk) at Christmas. As can be seen by the Dickens reference, this historical usage persists on the American side of the pond.

But you might object: Isn't there plenty of drinking on New Year's Eve? Again, history plays a role.

> A prominent educator and patron of the arts, Henry Cole travelled in
> the elite, social circles of early Victorian England, and had the
> misfortune of having too many friends.
>
> During the holiday season of 1843, those friends were causing Cole
> much anxiety.
>
> Cole hit on an ingenious idea. He approached an artist friend, J.C.
> Horsley, and asked him to design an idea that Cole had sketched out in
> his mind. Cole then took Horsley’s illustration—a triptych showing a
> family at table celebrating the holiday flanked by images of people
> helping the poor—and had a thousand copies made by a London printer.
> The image was printed on a piece of stiff cardboard 5 1/8 x 3 1/4
> inches in size. At the top of each was the salutation, “TO:_____”
> allowing Cole to personalize his responses, which included the generic
> greeting “A Merry Christmas and A Happy New Year To You.”
>
> It was the first Christmas card.

(From "The History of the Christmas Card", by John Hanc, published at [SmithsonianMag.com](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/history-christmas-card-180957487/).)

[image: First Christmas Card]

### TL;DR

"A Merry Christmas and A Happy New Year to you" were on the first Christmas Card and have stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As Gnawme said, we're perfectly happy with 'Happy Christmas' in the UK. But when we put the two together, we'd probably say 'a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year'. Why that way round? Well, as you say, 'Merry New Year doesn't sound right', and I think Kris has given you exactly the answer why.

Comment: I think it's ok because we are less reliant on catchphrases than our US friends and it makes perfectly good sense. However that doesn't mean it is the norm, which some people seem to have been mislead to believe.  Just like "enjoy your birthday" isn't wrong but it's not the saying.

Answer (score 0):

merry Christmas and happy New Year are the commonly ones known by all. In my opinion, merry simply depicts vivacity and optimism. In this sense, it suggests more should be expected in the years ahead. Whereas happy unsophisticatedly demonstrates  pleasure, satisfaction, gratification or fulfillment.

You can vividly conclude that merry which means expectation. It ushers individuals into the state of fulfillment, satisfaction and excitement into the present and future. Hence, it is just appropriate to have Merry Christmas and Happy New Year rather than Happy Christmas and Merry New Year.

Additionally, Christmas is commemorated within the last few days to the closure of the year, and it is short lived and enjoyed, while New Year has a lengthy period. It means before the next merriment, you would have been fulfilled, satisfied and willing to gratify the maker of all things for another merry Christmas which places you in high pedestal of expectation before stepping confidently into another new year.  -- Rachel Pauline Aikins, Ghana, East Legon

Answer (score -1):

Why is it [*“Merry” Christmas* but *“Happy” New Year*](https://www.events2021.com/merry-christmas-and-happy-new-year/)? Could we say *Merry New Year*, which sounds wrong to me? *Merry* is attached only to *Christmas*, not to *New Year*.

I propose *merry* implies more short-term jollity and *happy* more long-term contentment.

Comment: Where have you found this information?

Comment: This is a copy of what has already been posted elsewhere on this page.