# Single verb for 'being merry during Christmas'

Tags: single-word-requests, greetings, christmas

Is there a single verb that means "to be merry during Christmas" but excludes being merry or happy at New Year?

Comment: I'm fairly certain we're going to need a neologism.

Comment: Just turn *Nowell* into a verb.

Comment: I'd post "No" as an answer, but the system won't accept answers that short, and I bet it'd get more downvotes than upvotes... :-)

Comment: @snailboat: all you have to do is find the antonym for *Russian*. Because Russians do not celebrate Christmas at all (certainly not in December), while New Year's Eve is *the* main holiday of the entire year.

Comment: Hm... The title is broader than the body.

Comment: Verbing weirds language.

Comment: @Ste Not nearly as much as a 30-letter neologism :-)

Comment: @AndrewLeach True dat!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, but that’s not as native-English-y-sounding as *yuleglee*, I’m sure you’d agree!

Comment: As a Briton, I find "on Christmas" weirder than "Anteneoannusnoelojollification".  We get merry "at Christmas", if at all.

Comment: Dropping in to point out that until the last couple hundred yrs or so,  Christmas was a very solemn holiday (at least for some Christian sects). St. Nicolas' Day came somewhat sooner in December and was party time.   Me, I'll stick with the Saturnalia :-)

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has said `Christmassy` - as in, "I'm feeling very Christmassy", or, "I don't want to see Bob, he's going to be all christmassy and I'm not in the mood". Or, almost the same, `festive`.

Comment: @user568458, Christmassy is good, "festive" can be any occasion.  I'd vote for Christmassy, though!

Comment: A word may have many synonyms. Asking for the synonyms of a word is not inviting "opinion", even though several disparate "answers" may be offered. Conversely. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I thought of wassailing, but apparently it's done on 12th Night, which is after New Year's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One might propose *yulegaiety* or *yuleglee*, although whether that implies *anniënnui* I am uncertain.

Answer (score 48):

I am going to propose ***"Anteneoannusnoelojollification"***

Built from

- *ante* — Before
- *neo* — new
- *annus* — year
- *noel* — Christmas
- *o* — bridging vowel for word fluidity
- *jollification* — the act of jollifying, making happy.

> Making something merry at Christmas before the New Year.

No citations until it makes it into the OED.

Comment: Unfortunately if you forget the second *n* in *annus* it becomes the happy anticipation of someone tearing you a new one during the holidays.

Comment: @BenJackson hey, if you're into that sort of thing. I'm not here to judge.

Comment: I think they prefer this word on Raxacoricofallapatorius.

Comment: They ought to use this word as a sobriety test! "Say this three times fast, sir: Anteneoannusnoelojollification"

Comment: @KristinaLopez now be honest, did you type that or copy-paste?  ;)

Comment: Copy/paste of course.  I was terrified of leaving off the 2nd "n"! lol!

Comment: Can you use this in a sentence?

Comment: @netinept Of course. "On December 25th I will be bringing an abundance of anteneoannusnoelojolification to my friends on EL&U"

Comment: I'm sorry, but did we somehow navigate to the German Language & Usage Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Ste Are those friends *still* around?

Comment: @NobleUplift We are very much on the Germanic language & usage stack exchange site.

Comment: Good, because English ain't got nothin' on long German words. Well, except antidisestablishmentarianism. I love antidisestablishmentarianism and consider myself an antidisestablishmentarianist.

Answer (score 16):

Neologisms ahoy ...

- I'm having some major jollitude
- I'm feeling Santastic
- I'm all falala
- I'm totally kringled right now.

Comment: I am absolutely going to use these. Brilliant.

Comment: I'd vote twice if I could!  Definitely recommending you for Santa's "Nice" list! :-)

Answer (score 6):

*Merry* is reserved (by whom?) for Christmas; *Happy* is for the New Year.

This has been documented.

*meta*: I feel it has also been mentioned here on ELU around Christmas last year. [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/52709/14666)?

Non-word: *[noëlfun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfa83.gif)*.

Comment: *Merry* can also mean *drunk* at any time of the year.

Comment: I've seen "Happy Christmas," as well as "Happy Christmas and a merry New Year" many times. The two words are hardly "reserved."

Comment: Oughtn’t that be *noëlfun*, lest it be confused for its antonym?

Comment: @tchrist, right, pity the grumpy elves.

Comment: @MrHen: Tx. But let there be fun.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *unchristmassing* because *Christmas* is [an exclamation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Christmas?q=christmas) expressing:

> surprise, dismay, or despair.

So if you are unchristmassing you are being the opposite of those things, which sounds good.

Since it contains the word *christmas*, it should only be used at that time of year.

Comment: I've never heard "Christmas" used as an exclamation, but I might try to get it going in the UK.

Comment: This immediately explains the alien attacks that always happen to fall on Christmas. Or is it the other way around?

Comment: First OED citation for *Christmas* used as an interjection is “1897 Kipling *Capt. Cour.* iv. 91 — Jiminy Christmas! That gives me the blue creevles.” which I thought went with crickets. Last OED citation as interjection is “1959 N. Marsh *False Scent* (1960) vi. 192 - ‘All right with you, Bertie?’ ‘Oh, Christmas!’ he said. ‘I suppose so.’ ”

Comment: Be aware that "Christmas" used as an exclamation is a [minced oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) for "Christ". The Kipling reference is a double-minced oath, since "Jiminy Cricket" is itself a minced oath for "Jesus Christ".

Answer (score 1):

Jolly.  Never really used except during the holidays.

Happy Jollydays...

Answer (score 0):

For the common vernacular, I shall suggest "Christmerrymas".  A portmonteau of Merry and Christmas with no mention of the New Years at all.

I'm curious as to why you're so admant about people not being merry for the New Years though.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn’t.

The English language isn’t a code for expressing detailed complicated ideas in single words. Did the poster or anyone else really need such a thing?

Comment: No, the poster needed a [winter hat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/12/16/winter-bash-2013-is-here/) :)

Answer (score -1):

***christmasyaynewyearsnay***:

- Christmas
- Yay
- New Years
- Nay

---

I think this sums it up in a very matter-of-fact way *and is also how I feel regarding the matter =D*

Comment: Love it! Love it!