# My exams have been preponed

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

In India, most educated People say that " my exams have been preponed" As an English teacher I know that Americans say moved up and Britishers say that advanced in the context. One of the best English professors I know in India says that prepone is the right word in the context.Even some native speakers said that the word prepone could be accepted.
I would like to know the opinion of the experts in the group.

Comment: Questions about *prepone* appear here regularly. Try searching for them, you’ll likely find the info you seek.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, then you need to make your question more precise. There's no institution, government, or person who decides what words are and aren't accepted (see [for example this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197096/how-to-name-or-define-a-new-word)).