# Happy Merry Christmas vs Merry Christmas

Tags: expressions, differences, expression-choice

I was wondering whether it is incorrect to say, "Happy merry Christmas.". Please give some reasons.

Comment: "Happy merry Christmas" is not idiomatic and a bit nonsensical.  "Happy" and "merry" are near-synonyms, and so stringing them together (while not technically illegal grammar) is "redundant".  (Cue the voice of doom!)  You may say "happy Christmas" or, more commonly in the US, "merry Christmas".

Comment: @HotLicks Ah, the problem is redundancy. I thank you, and wish you a merry, merry Christmas!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52709/why-is-it-merry-christmas-but-happy-new-year/52712#52712).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying it would not be incorrect, but, when writing it, you should put a comma between the adjectives.

> Have a happy, merry Christmas!

As [this website](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/042301comcoordadj.htm) says:

> Put commas between coordinate adjectives, but because it is not always easy to tell when adjectives are coordinate, we apply two simple tests to be sure:
>
> First, we try placing the word *and* between the two adjectives. Second, we reverse them. If, in both instances, the resulting phrase still sounds appropriate, we are most likely dealing with coordinate adjectives and should use a comma between them.

With that, have a merry and happy Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as humor.
"Happy Christmas" for the UK and "Merry Christmas" for the US.
For a gathering with both groups present: "Happy Merry Christmas".