# Merry Easter to all of you!

Tags: word-usage

It may sound strange, but why is *Merry* not used with Easter? Is there a reason why its usage  has been so firmly fixed with Christmas?

Comment: Related: *[Determining which good sentiment to wish at each holiday](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44588)*, *[Why is it “Merry” Christmas, but “Happy” New Year?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52709)* and *[Is there a season's greeting for Halloween?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46775)* plus the ["Getting into the spirit" blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/getting-into-the-spirit/).

Comment: @Waggers: Neither that question nor any of the answers are directed towards this question. That just talks about what, not why. Why not 'Merry' with 'Easter'?

Comment: @Mitch On the contrary, that question starts with the words "Is there any rhyme or reason..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine Christians would say that Christmas = birth of Christ = good news and that Easter = crucifixion of Christ = not such good news. But then the resurrection seems to be good news, so it's all a bit confusing.

Comment: Easter is DEFINITELY good news.

Comment: You know what Jesus said about Good Friday though. "No, really, what's good about it?"

Comment: @MετάEd - "I'm gonna paint the town red; it's payday!!!" - Judas